# Reset the sum when calculating average

Tags: c++, sum, average

I have a program that asks a user how many quizzes they would like to input, stores the grades, and the computes the average. The grade has to be between 0 and 100. However, when I enter a grade above 100 the average is wrong. It does not reset the sum. If I enter 120 and it prompts me to reenter the grades, it still uses 120 when calculating the average. How do I get it to reset?

Note: I do not want to change the the format (such as using a while loop).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n, i;
    float num[13], sum=0.0, average;
    cout << "Enter the numbers of quizzes from 1-13: ";
    cin >> n;

while (n < 1 || n > 13)
{
    cout << "You must enter a number from 1 - 13." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of quizzes you would like to input(1-13): “;
    cin >> n;

}


for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
       cout << i+1 << ". Enter number: ";
       cin >> num[i];
       sum+=num[i];


    while (num[i] < 0 || num[i] > 100)
    {
    cout << “You must enter a number between 0 and 100. Re enter scores.”;
        cout << i+1 << ". Enter number: ";
        cin >> num[i];
    }
  }

   average=sum/n;
   cout << "Average = " << average;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the `sum+=num[i]` behind the `while (num[i] < 0 || num[i] > 100) ...` loop !

This way you only sum up valid numbers.

```
for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
   cout << i+1 << ". Enter number: ";
   cin >> num[i];
   //sum+=num[i]; remove here !!

   while (num[i] < 0 || num[i] > 100)
   {
    cout << “You must enter a number between 0 and 100. Re enter scores.”;
    cout << i+1 << ". Enter number: ";
    cin >> num[i];
   }

   sum+=num[i]; // <- insert here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
       cout << i+1 << ". Enter number: ";
       cin >> num[i];

    while (num[i] < 0 || num[i] > 100)
    {
    cout << “You must enter a number between 0 and 100. Re enter scores.”;
        cout << i+1 << ". Enter number: ";
        cin >> num[i];
    }
  }


   sum+=num[i];
   average=sum/n;
   cout << "Average = " << average;
   return 0;
}
```